# Payara 5 HTTPS extremely slow

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, payara

I've met a really strange case:

Before migrating to Payara 5.182, I use Payara 4.1.181, and the http/https requests are all very fast. Things go strange when I migrate to Payara 5.182, http requests are working just fine, but the https requests are extremely slow.

Here's the information:

- the application that deployed to Payara 5.182 / Payara 4.1.181 is the same version
- configure the keystore.jks and cacerts.jks in Payara 5.182 just the same way as Payara 4.1.181:

  - `keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore 3MEdu.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -alias 3medu_cert`
  - `keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore cacerts.jks -srckeystore 3MEdu.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -alias 3medu_cert`
- the 3MEdu.p12 is the same file as used in Payara 4.1.181
- use 80 port for http request and 443 port for https request
- JDK version: Oracle JDK 8u161
- OS verison: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One difference between Payara 4 and 5 is that HTTP/2 is enabled by default in Payara 5. Try disabling HTTP2 as described in the documentation: https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/payara-server/server-configuration/http/protocols.html

Comment: Has anyone ever found the reason why HTTP2 with Glassfish 5 has this speed problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, @Jan, but I suspect it might be caused by some memory leaks or race conditions in Grizzly. In Payara Server, many of them were fixed since version 5.182: [HTTP/2 Server Push Issues](https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/3690), [HTTP/2 Trailer Issue](https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/3545), [HTTP/2 Memory Leak](https://github.com/payara/patched-src-grizzly/pull/14), [Updated Grizzly](https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/2921). It's worth trying HTTP/2 with the latest Payara Server version.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this, the complete menu are:

Network Config -> Network Listeners -> http-listener-2 - HTTP TAG an search the HTTP/2 Option to disable